# Como pegar valores de dois selects do html em javascript?

Tags: javascript, java, html, html5, html-select

Basicamente eu tenho o código abaixo:

```js
var associar = $("#associar");
var desassociar = $("#desassociar");
var permissoes = $("#permissoes");
var minhasPermissoes = $("#minhasPermissoes");
var gravar = $("#gravar");

associar.click(function() {
  minhasPermissoes.append(permissoes.find('option:selected'));
});

desassociar.click(function() {
  permissoes.append(minhasPermissoes.find('option:selected'));
});

gravar.click(function(){
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <label>Permissões</label>
      <select id="permissoes" class="form-control" multiple>
        <option value="Clientes">Clientes</option>
        <option value="Boletos">Boletos</option>
        <option value="Usuarios">Usuários</option>
        <option value="Configuracoes">Configurações</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <label>Minhas Permissões</label>
      <select id="minhasPermissoes" class="form-control" multiple>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <button id="associar" class="btn btn-primary">Associar</button>
  <button id="desassociar" class="btn btn-primary">Desassociar</button>
 <button id="gravar" class="btn btn-primary" style="float:right;">Gravar</button>
 <div id="texto">
 </div>
```

Como podem ver executando o código, eu passo valores(Object) de uma caixa de seleção pra outra e vice-versa, eu gostaria de que quando clicar em gravar eu passo os objetos dessas caixas de seleção como uma List, para ser tratado no Controller.

Tentei fazer da seguinte forma, que acaba me retornando uma List mas só vem um objeto.

```js
var perfisUtilizados = [];
perfisUtilizados = $('#selectPerfisUtilizados').find('option');
var perfisDisponiveis = [];
perfisDisponiveis = $('#selectPerfisDisponiveis').find('option');

gravar..click(function() {
  location.href = '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/permissao/perfis/${id}/' + perfisUtilizados + "," + perfisDisponiveis;
});
```

E quando clicar no gravar passa pra esse metodo do Controller:

```
@Get("/permissao/perfis/{id}/{perfisUtilizados},{perfisDisponiveis}")
public void salvarPerfisDaPermissao(Long id, List<Perfil> perfisUtilizados,
        List<Perfil> perfisDisponiveis){
  //Implementação
}
```

Como resolver?

Comment: Qual o padrão esperado pelo servidor? Palavras separadas por vírgula? Não seria melhor enviar esses dados no corpo da requisição?

Comment: @Nevershowmyface o esperado pelo servidor seria 2 Listas do tipo Perfil, esse é o objeto passado no value, acima é apenas um exemplo para que possa ser exemplificado e possa mostrar o funcionamento, como enviaria os dados no corpo da requisição?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizando jQuery, você pode enviar as listas de permissões dentro do corpo da requisição em formato JSON assim

```
gravar.click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'}
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,                                  // Substitua pela URL do sistema
    data: JSON.stringify({
      permissoes: permissoes.find('option').map(function() {
        return this.value;
      }).toArray(),
      minhasPermissoes: minhasPermissoes.find('option').map(function() {
        return this.value;
      }).toArray()
    }),
  }).done(function(response, event_type) {     // Em caso de sucesso
    console.log('done', response, event_type);
  }).fail(function(response, event_type) {     // Em caso de falha
    console.log('fail', response, event_type);
  }).always(function(response, event_type) {   // Depois do sucesso/falha
    console.log('always', response, event_type);
  })
});
```

Inspecione as variáveis `response` e `event_type`, pela ferramenta de desenvolvedor, para realizar o tratamento necessário no lado do cliente.

Como eu não programo em Java não saberia dizer como os dados serão recebidos no lado do servidor mas a intenção é enviar um objeto com o seguinte padrão:

```
{
  "permissoes": ["Clientes", "Boletos"],
  "minhasPermissoes": ["Configuracoes", "Usuarios"],
}
```